# Changing sizes between layouts

Tags: java, android, xml, fragment

I have a `LinearLayout`. In it, I have a few `Fragments`. I want to use my top `Fragment` in another `Activity` but keep it the exact same size. My issue is, the next `Activity` is a `RelativeLayout` and `android:weightSum` is not usable. How can I keep my dimensions from `LinearLayout` to `RelativeLayout`?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/appmenu"
    android:weightSum="6.5">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/titlebar"
        class="com.abc.appname.titlebar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mainmenubuttons"
        class="com.abc.appname.mainmenubuttons"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4.5"/>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/bottombar"
        class="com.abc.appname.bottombar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Solution:
I used RelativeLayout Percentages as suggested below. I would like to note I had to add a few things to get it to work correctly including:

In Gradle:

```
 compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.3.0'
```

In the XML:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

Hope this helps the next guy :)

Comment: post code of `RelativeLayout`'s `Acitivity`

Comment: Right now the Activity just has a RelativeLayout with nothing in it since I can't get specific sizes for fragments. It will be close to identical to the LinearLayout. I would have no problems switching the LL to a RL but, I am trying to keep proportions between screen sizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **ParcentRelativeLayout** library https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html

simple implementation

```
  <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/appmenu"
    >
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/titlebar"
        class="com.abc.appname.titlebar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"

         app:layout_heightPercent="14.5%"/>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mainmenubuttons"
        class="com.abc.appname.mainmenubuttons"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"

         app:layout_heightPercent="69%"/>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/bottombar"
        class="com.abc.appname.bottombar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"

        app:layout_heightPercent="14.5%"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! I didn't know this existed. Exactly what I was looking for.